# Reading Empty Cell of Excel Sheet

Tags: java, sql, excel, datatable

I am reading contents of the excel sheet using the following code.

```
     for (Row row : sheet) {
                Cell firstCell = row.getCell(0);
                Cell secondCell = row.getCell(1);
                Cell thirdCell = row.getCell(2);
                Cell fourthCell = row.getCell(3);
                Cell fifthCell = row.getCell(4);

                urlcnt=firstCell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
                srccnt=secondCell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
                contentType=thirdCell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
                verticle=fourthCell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
                timeFrame=fifthCell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
}
```

I am assigning each cell of a particular row to a string as above.

```
PreparedStatement insertUrlStatement = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO urls_temp(url, source_name, is_active, is_periodic, Link_Type, New_Entry, verticle, periodic_timeframe, datentime) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

insertUrlStatement.setString(1, urlcnt);
                            insertUrlStatement.setString(2, srccnt);
                            insertUrlStatement.setInt(3, 1);
                            insertUrlStatement.setInt(4, 0);
                            insertUrlStatement.setString(5, contentType);
                            insertUrlStatement.setInt(6, 1);
                            insertUrlStatement.setString(7, verticle);
                            insertUrlStatement.setString(8, timeFrame);
                            insertUrlStatement.setString(9, datentime);
                            insertUrlStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Sometimes in the excel sheet, a cell may be left empty in a row by the user.
During such cases this program is not inserting that whole row.

I want the empty cell to be saved as null in the table urls_temp.

How to attain the same? Please advise...

Comment: Does the table urls_temp have a constraint that requires url to be non-null or to have a length greater than zero?

Answer (score 0):

this might be an idea. Use a function which fills null in the statment if the supplied variable is empty. You might need to experiment with the (text = null) part but this could to the job. Sorry for my poor coding style. You will need such a function for any datatype.

```
function bindString(int column, String text) {

  If (text == null) then
    insertUrlStatement.setNull(column, STRING);
  Else
    insertUrlStatement.setString(column, text);
  EndIf

}
```